# viewpager dont work when viewpager and scrollview in same layour

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview

I have an viewpager and textview in same layout. i want to make textview scroll veritical,and when user scroll horizitial in this textview, viewpager can scroll.  but its dont work now  plase help me  thanks.

here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_test"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.will.custom_rxandroid.ui.TestActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Touch event conflict,[see this](http://blog.csdn.net/mcy478643968/article/details/19609407).

Comment: thanks a log, but this question is that my textview and viewpager in same layout rather than that textview inside viewpager